# eclipse : how can I edit package name of android project?

Tags: android, eclipse

In eclipse, How can I edit package name of android project?

I know I can re-create project and copy source, but I don't want to re-create project;

Answer (score 1):

> Right click on Package Name > Android Tools> Rename Application Package

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project -> android tools -> rename application package

Answer (score 0):

if you are using eclipse then you can user following method

1. Right click on project -> android tools -> rename application package
2. Right click on package which you want to rename and choose refractor > rename

Answer (score 0):

Right click on package which you want to rename and choose refractor > rename